# Primes Powers and Mods

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The Question is below:

For which primes $p$ is $(p − 1)^p + 1$ a power of $p$?

I think the answer is $2$ and $3$, none of the others work.

Here is what I have:

let $p^k-1=(p-1)^p$. Then we have $$p^{k-1}+...+p+1 \equiv0 \pmod{p-1}.$$

---

Please also include a proof of your answer

Comment: But if $0 \leq l < k$, $p^l=1$ mod $p-1$... so you must have $p-1|k$.

Comment: The equation should be $\dots +p^2+p+1\equiv\dots.$ You left out the $p.$

Comment: @Mindlack what do you mean?

Comment: Was my answer to your satisfaction?

Comment: I did figure out a better solution, but yes it was

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $(p-1)^p+1=p^k$ then

\begin{align*}
k&=\log_p \left(1+(p-1)^p\right)\\
&=\log_p \left(p^p \left(\frac{1}{p^p}+\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^p\right)\right)\\
&=p+\log_p \left(\frac{1}{p^p}+\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^p\right)
\end{align*}

clearly

$$\log_p \left(\frac{1}{p^p}+\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^p\right)<0$$

since $\frac{1}{p^p}+\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^p<1$

and so it suffices to show that

$$\log_p \left(\frac{1}{p^p}+\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^p\right)>-1$$

for $p>3$ since then $p+\log_p \left(\frac{1}{p^p}+\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^p\right)$ cannot be an integer for $p>3$. Differentiating $\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$ we get that it is an increasing function and so for $p\geq5$ we get that

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\geq\left(1-\frac{1}{5}\right)^5>.3$$

for $p\geq5$ we also clearly have that $\frac{1}{p}\leq \frac{1}{5}=.2$: it is thus that

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{p^p}+\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^p &> \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^p\\
&>.3\\
&>.2\\
&\geq \frac{1}{p}
\end{align*}

taking logs base $p$ of both sides gets that

$$\log_p \left(\frac{1}{p^p}+\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^p\right)>-1$$

and our proof is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $(p-1)^p=p^n-1$ for some prime $p$ and some positive integer $n$.

Observe that $(p,n)=(2,1),(3,2)$ are solutions. We claim there aren't any more.

Suppose $p \ge 5$. From the Binomial Theorem,

$$ (p-1)^p = p^n-1 = \big((p-1)+1\big)^n - 1 = \sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} (p-1)^k, $$

so that

$$ (p-1)^{p-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n \choose k} (p-1)^k. $$

But now the LHS is a multiple of $p-1$ whereas the RHS is $1$ more than a multiple of $p-1$. Since $p-1 \ne 1$, this is impossible.

Therefore,

$$ (p-1)^p+1 = p^n \Longleftrightarrow (p,n) = (2,1)\:\text{or}\:(3,2). $$